# CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY Error while updating Opportunity TerritoryId (std.Field)

Tags: apex

I am getting below error while updating TerritoryId(Standard Salesforce field) on opportunity using Apex.

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: []

details of the issue:

1. 'User A' is updating an Opportunity owned by 'User B'.
2. As per the code, (with sharing enabled in class) , i take the Opportunity sales team active member TerritoryId on Opportunity. Then i am getting the error.
3. if user A is updating Territory Id on Opportunity manually, then user is not getting the error.
4. if i remove 'With Sharing' keyword then also i am not getting error. But this is not right practice since we have Sharing rules enabled.

Note:

1. Opportunity sharing model is Private
2. both users have read,edit,create access on Account, Opportunity
3. have Territory Assignment rule on Account gives read access on Account,  read    edit access on opportunity. And users A & B both fall under same territory.
4. Opportunity Sharing rule gives RW access to User A as well as user B.
5. User A profile(Sales admin) is more wider than user B profile(sales rep).
6. Account & Opportunity share shows territory of the users i.e. territory have access to account & Opportunity.

Not sure what is causing the issue. Appreciate if anyone help me in cracking this issue. here is the code snippet executes in sharing mode: updating existing account team as well as account team member terr id on opportunity update.

```
for (Opportunity opportunity : opptyMap.values()) {
  if (accntToOpptyTeamTypesMap.keySet().contains(opportunity.AccountId)) {
    Map<Id, String> btInnerMap = accntToOpptyTeamTypesMap.get(
      opportunity.AccountId);
    for (Id btId : btInnerMap.keySet()) {
      if (opptyToTeamTypesMap.get(opportunity.Id) == btInnerMap.get(btId)) {
        Opportunity opptyRcd = new Opportunity(Id = opportunity.Id);
        opptyRcd.Sales_Team__c = btId;
        if (bTeamMemTerrIdMap.containsKey(btId)) {
          opptyRcd.TerritoryId = bTeamMemTerrIdMap.get(btId); //getting teritory Id from team
        }
        updatedOpptyList.add(opptyRcd);
      }
    }
  }
}
if (!updatedOpptyList.isEmpty()) {
  if (OpportunityManagement.shouldRun) {
    OpportunityManagement.shouldRun = false;
    update updatedOpptyList;
    OpportunityManagement.shouldRun = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: And the code you are using?

Comment: Here is the code snippet that i use to update opportunity.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the code there, not in the comments

Comment: Finally solved the issue, by removing 'With Sharing' keyword since apex code couldn't resolve sharing rules as expected when territory as well as custom sharing rules are in place.